# Invalid array values ​in compute shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, compute-shader

I use a buffer to which I pass my C++ structures

```
struct Node {
    Node(int size, glm::ivec3 position);

    bool isEmpty();
    int getSubIndex(const glm::ivec3& vec);
    void divide(std::vector<Node> &nodes);
    void setColor(glm::vec4 color);
    int getSubNodeIndex(const glm::ivec3& vec);
    int getSubNodeIndex(int subIndex);

    glm::ivec4 position;
    glm::vec4 color;
    int halfSize;
    int sub;
    int leaf;
};
```

In the shader it looks like this

```
struct Node {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
    int data[3];
};

layout(std430, binding=4) readonly buffer Octree_data {
    Node nodes[];
};
```

In the process of calculations, I find out that in all elements of the array (except for the first element) there are incorrect data (most likely displaced) in what could I make a mistake?

Comment: An array is not the same as three distinct variables. If you want to have an array of integers in the shader, you must have the corresponding array in the C++ code.

Comment: As for the likely reason, see [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: I tried the option with three different int variables, there is the same result =( sizeof(Node) outputs 44

Comment: I found out that each variable in my shader takes up 16 bytes, for a total of 80, while my C++ structure is only 44, how to correctly load the data?

Comment: @KirillGurevich: "*I found out that each variable in my shader takes up 16 bytes, for a total of 80*" How did you find this out? `std430` layout doesn't say that.

Comment: I used glGetActiveUniformBlockiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std430` required alignment for your `Node` structure is 16-bytes. This is because it contains a 16-byte-aligned type (`vec4` and `ivec4`). Therefore, every array element in the `Node` array will have to start at a 16-byte boundary. So the array stride for `nodes` will have to be 48.

The C++ alignment of your `Node` structure is probably 4 bytes. This is because nothing *in C++'s layout* for your `Node` structure requires higher alignment. GLM's 4-element vector types are 4-byte aligned (or rather, they're `float` aligned, which is almost always 4 bytes). This means that the `sizeof(Node)` will be 44 bytes, as will the array stride.

If you want your C++ struct to match the GLSL required layout, you need to align it properly:

```
struct Node {
    Node(int size, glm::ivec3 position);

    bool isEmpty();
    int getSubIndex(const glm::ivec3& vec);
    void divide(std::vector<Node> &nodes);
    void setColor(glm::vec4 color);
    int getSubNodeIndex(const glm::ivec3& vec);
    int getSubNodeIndex(int subIndex);

    alignas(16) glm::ivec4 position;
    alignas(16) glm::vec4 color;
    int halfSize;
    int sub;
    int leaf;
};
```

Comment: [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), TIL.

Comment: I did as you said, sizeof outputted 48 instead of 44 =( apparently I made a mistake somewhere !!!! 
I'm sorry, I just noticed that everything is as you said, now I'll check for errors

Comment: Yes, it helped, thank you very much for your help, I was already thinking about making tricky designs)